# Keeping focus on previous application in WPF

Tags: wpf, input, focus, hook

I am trying of creating a WPF application which will be used by touch display device to input shortcuts within third party applications.

The idea seemed simple, something similar to how the on screen keyboard work on windows. However I quickly discovered a major obstacle; while I can easily simulate inputs, I cannot find a way of sending them to the appropriate application or control. As soon as a button is clicked, the previous application loose focus and the inputs are not sent to the correct location.

I have done plenty of research but unfortunately it seems that everybody are usually trying to control the focus of multiple windows within the same application.

Im unsure if this is possible at all using the core assemblies. I would prefer not having to do any dll imports but I am afraid this might be necessary.

Please let me know if you have any solutions or directions that I could explore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the focussed element (name / reference).
2. Show the VirtualKeyboard.
3. Handle the button press events at the root level of VK user-control. From the common event handler, you can manipulate the text shown in the stored focussed element easily, using its Text property. You have to use switch-case for various buttons like(Backspace etc). As VKeyboard has minimum needed keys only, so this will work without problems.

Comment: Hello Anjum,
How exactly are you going to store the reference of the last focused element outside the application? As far as I know there isn't any way of getting references of the objects outside the application with the event managers and we can't setup hooks on every applications right?

Comment: It looks like you are trying some hacking. I thought that virtual keyboard is shown within the same app. But still you can do what you are trying to do using Win32 functions. You can get handle of the textbox.